# How to create and assert a Mockito list of custom object?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to simplify a test case 1st code block to something similar shown in the 2nd code block.
I have two questions:

1. Can I mock a list of custom objects?
2. Can I assert a mocked list of custom objects with the fields in a returned list of objects?

Is something similar achieveable?

```
  @Test
    public void testStudentSuccess() {
    Student st = new Student();
        st.setRollNumber("1234");
        st.setFeeAmount("1000");
        List<Student> stList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        stList.add(st);
        Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        simpleJdbcCallResult.put("X_GET_DATA", stList);
        when(simpleJdbcCall.getSimpleJdbcCall(any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class),
                        any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class),
                        any(StudentRowMapper.class))).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCallResult);
        List<Student> studentList = opusPackageRepo.getPolicyStudent("123", "123");
        Student student = studentList.get(0);
        assertEquals(student.getRollNumber(), "1234");
        assertEquals(student.getFeeAmount(), "1000");
    }
```

To something like this (see the comments -> //):

```
@Test
    public void testStudentSuccess() {
        List<Student> stList = Mockito.mock(new ArrayList<Student>()); // 1. IS SOMTHING SIMILAR TO THIS POSSIBLE?
        Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        simpleJdbcCallResult.put("X_GET_DATA", Mockito.mock(new ArrayList<Student>()));
        when(simpleJdbcCall.getSimpleJdbcCall(any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class),
                        any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class),
                        any(StudentRowMapper.class))).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCallResult);
        List<Student> studentList = opusPackageRepo.getPolicyStudent("123", "123");
        assertEquals(studentList, stList); // 2. CAN I ASSERT EQUALS A MOCK WITH A RETURNED LIST?
    }
```

Comment: The only thing thats worth mocking here is opusPackageRepo. Whats the point of mocking a list here

Comment: I think the answer below by @glitch was what I was looking for - "Your test does not need to know about the contents of this List"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original test in your OP you are creating an expected result for the `simpleJdbcCall.getSimpleJdbcCall()` as follows:

```
Student st = new Student();
st.setRollNumber("1234");
st.setFeeAmount("1000");
List<Student> stList = new ArrayList<Student>();
stList.add(st);
Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = new HashMap<String, Object>();
simpleJdbcCallResult.put("X_GET_DATA", stList);
```

Then you assert that the result (which `opusPackageRepo.getPolicyStudent()` must access via the `"X_GET_DATA"` key) matches your expectation:

```
Student student = studentList.get(0);
assertEquals(student.getRollNumber(), "1234");
assertEquals(student.getFeeAmount(), "1000");
```

You could simplfy this without any need to think about mocks ...

```
List<Student> expected = new ArrayList<Student>();
Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = new HashMap<String, Object>();
simpleJdbcCallResult.put("X_GET_DATA", expected);

...

List<Student> actual = opusPackageRepo.getPolicyStudent("123", "123");
assertSame(expected, actual);
```

This verifies that the result returned by `getPolicyStudent` **is** the same as the list returned by the `simpleJdbcCall.getSimpleJdbcCall()` invocation.

Your test does not need to know about the contents of this List since your test is just concerned with verifying that the List returned by `simpleJdbcCall.getSimpleJdbcCall()` is correctly passed on by `getPolicyStudent` reading it from this key: `"X_GET_DATA"`. I *think* this is what you were hinting at when you wrote "simplify a test case" and it can be easily done but it does not need any mocking.